# How to exclude a subnet from TC qdisc rule?

Tags: tc

I need to add an artificial delay to outgoing traffic from my server's `eth0` interface using the Linux command `tc` (Traffic Control). I would like to add such a delay to all packets except those directed to a subnet, for example 191.168.1.0/24.

So far I have used the following command that add a delay to all packets without applying any filter to the traffic.

```bash
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 20ms
```

How should I modify the commands to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.qdisc.filters.html